# Reverse url lookup with include parameter

Tags: python, django

Does anyone know how to make a reverse url lookup on a url with an include parameter? For example I have the following url:

```
 url(r'^photos/', include('photos.urls'), name="photos"),
```

And in my view i want to access it as follows

```
def photos_redirect(request, path):
    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(reverse('photos') + path)
```

But it get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'photos' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Comment: You cannot reverse an 'include' url. You have to redirect each url in the photos/urls.py separately or you can use your web server's (Apache, NginX, IIS) method of redirecting obsolete URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reverse to a single urlpattern. The `photos` URL pattern is including all the urlpatterns in `photos.urls`, so you have to choose which single URL you are wanting to direct to.